# UnicodeEncodeError while displaying output on screen

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file in S3 which prints out part of the file name with delimiter which is dynamic and then the JSON data itself. I want to remove the characters while reading the file from s3.

Sample data is like this:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| File name | `XYZ_445643_Split0_A.json` |
| Data | `445643_Split0_A##{"Data":[{..},{..}]}` |

I am trying to read the file in Python

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.client("s3") 
response = s3.get_object(Bucket=some_bucket,Key=some_bucket/XYZ_445643_Split0_A.json)
data = response["Body"].read().decode("utf-8") 
data = data.split('##')[1]
```

Getting below error while printing the output on screen:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position: character maps to undefined
```

Comment: You’re not doing any encoding are you sure you aren’t done python 2 which has implicit encoding?

Comment: ya you are right. The error is encountered while doing .decode("utf-8"). I removed the encoding and getting TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not str with .split. I am using Python 3

Comment: the error is resolved with data = data.split(b'##')[1]. Is this the solution or is there better option to handle this.

Comment: `.decode()` error would be Unicode**Decode**Error on Python 3.

Comment: Can you please [edit] the question to clarify what you are asking? Right now there are at least two separate questions here - one is how to remove certain characters (a prefix?), and one is how to fix the UnicodeEncodeError. Please pick one and provide enough details for others to understand the problem unambigously.

Comment: The issue as encountered while printing the output on screen. I am able to loop through the json data and get the required keys and values.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to provide a [mre], then. Note that this can depend both on the content of the data as well as the envoding of terminal via which you are viewing the result.

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to convert the string to json

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json

rr = '445643_Split0_A##{"Data":[{"key": "value"},{"key1": "value1"}]}'
ss = json.loads(rr.split('##')[1])
print(ss["Data"])
print(ss["Data"][0])

for i in ss["Data"]:
    print(i)

for k,v in ss.items():
    print(k,v)

#[{'key': 'value'}, {'key1': 'value1'}]
#{'key': 'value'}
#{'key': 'value'}
#{'key1': 'value1'}
#Data [{'key': 'value'}, {'key1': 'value1'}]
```

Comment: I am doing json.loads in the next step. I end up getting the same unicode error.